Spring security & tomcat session persistence with redisson
For a high load Spring webapp I need to use multiple tomcat servers and a load balancer; this is done nicely and transparently by the Azure services. Sticky sessions help keep users on the same instance, but when the system scales down, all the users that have logged on the dissapearing instance have to log in again, obviously because they're not known on the remaining other instances.
So the next step is using session persistence; I have chosen redisson for this, and I can see the persisted data properly saved to the redis database.
The problem comes when the session has to be deserialized. I have traced the problem to the Spring Security class 'User', which has a member :
private final Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities;
that, at runtime holds an UnmodifiableCollection, which inevitably fires an UnsupportedOperationException when trying to be restored.
Here's what the redis database holds at runtime :

It seems to me that the serializer used is kryo. Why it's a List and not a Set, I haven't figured yet.
For reference, Spring version is 5.3.23 and Spring Security version is 5.7.3. Haven't tried other versions yet, but I don't think versions are of a crucial relevance here.
So the question are :

are Spring Security and redisson, more specifically kryo incompatible ?
is there any configuration variation that may help ?
what's the correct approach for this scenario ?
any best practices ?

Thank you.
